# objective C : refresh a view to display updated values

Tags: objective-c, uiview

I have a call back function, that on a certain event goes and updates a textField. I use an instance of the viewcontroller class, varViewController to access the textfield from the C code because I can't access the textfield and other members/outlets using self.

Now the problem is, when I update the textfield, it is not instantaneously updated. After I press any other button or do some action on the view, I see the updated value.

```
void abc(int a, char *b, char *c){

    current = a;

    if (varViewController == NULL)
        NSLog(@"\varViewController is empty");
    else
        NSLog(@"\varViewController");


    varViewController.tempAddress = @"GotSomething";

    [varViewController txtCallId ].text=@"CALLING CALLING";

}
```

My questions are :
First : Why is the value not getting updated as it is changed?

Second : How do I make the value appear as soon as it is changed??(value changed in c function).

Comment: You need to refresh the view. you can use delegate or notification to send that you have updated something. KVO...will help u

Comment: KVO?? could you please elaborate a little more.

Comment: Key Value Observer. its counter part for key value coding, notifications.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to force view to re-render try the following

```
[varViewController.view setNeedsDisplay];
```

Comment: I used the setNeedDisplay call, but still there is no change. The updated value is not getting redrawn as the function suggests.